# ComponentSelector doesn't return Components in the correct order

Tags: codenameone

For my use case it's crucial that `ComponentSelector.$("#...", myCnt)` returns the selected Components **in the same order in which they are shown in the given Container**, assuming that I'm using a `BoxLayout.y()` and that I add and remove Components before calling `ComponentSelector`.

Currently `ComponentSelector.$("#...", myCnt)` returns the Components in a random order.

Example:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        Label label1 = new Label("cmp 1");
        label1.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label2 = new Label("cmp 2");
        label2.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label3 = new Label("cmp 3");
        label3.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label4 = new Label("cmp 4");
        label4.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label5 = new Label("cmp 5");
        label5.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label6 = new Label("cmp 6");
        label6.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label7 = new Label("cmp 7");
        label7.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label8 = new Label("cmp 8");
        label8.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label9 = new Label("cmp 9");
        label9.setName("toBeSaved");
        Label label10 = new Label("cmp 10");
        label10.setName("toBeSaved");
        hi.addAll(label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10);
        hi.show();

        for (Component cmp : ComponentSelector.$("#toBeSaved", hi.getContentPane()).asList()) {
            if (cmp instanceof Label) {
                Log.p(((Label) cmp).getText());
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 2
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 7
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 8
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 1
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 6
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 4
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 3
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 9
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 10
[EDT] 0:0:0,153 - cmp 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because the class used `HashSet` to prevent duplicates. I replaced that with `LinkedHashSet` which should hopefully resolve the problem: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/2ef6a77e4f8ac3475a8c05541b8ac829099ac9a9